# How to improve the mysql "fetch" time of a result set?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that is a large data set needed for reporting purposes. Currently, the "duration" showing in MySQL workbench which I'm assuming to be execution time is about 7 seconds, so it is fairly optimized. It returns a measly 6000 rows, but it takes nearly 150 seconds to return them according to the "fetch" time.

Now, there are over 50 columns, which may explain some of the speed, but when I extracted the data set into a spreadsheet, it turned out to be about 4MB. I'm certainly not an expert, but I didn't expect 4MB to take 150 seconds to return over the pipe. I went ahead and performed the same query on a localhost setup to eliminate networking issues. Same result! It took about 7 seconds to execute, and 150 seconds to return the data on the same machine.

This report is expected to run real-time on demand, so having the end user wait 2 minutes is unacceptable for this use case. How can I improve the time it takes to return the data from MySQL?

**UPDATE: Thank you all for starting to point me in the right direction. As it turns out, the "duration" and "fetch" in workbench is horribly inaccurate. The two minutes I was experiencing   was all execution time and in fact my query needed optimizing. Thanks again, this was scratching my head. I will never rely on these metrics again...**

Comment: Which library are you using to generate spreadsheet? What is your code snippet? How much time it takes if you just echo count from results?

Comment: You need to optimize both the database and excel generation code. Please update you sql and cexcel generation code

Comment: Try running [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) to see what your query is doing.  Also, make sure your table structure is properly indexed.  Look up different optimizations you can do.  Look up caching.